# Is it possible to give an AD user 'write personal information' permissions without making them domain admin?

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I would like to allow a specific user the ability to update photos in AD, for example using a 3rd party utility that will be installed on their computer.   To do this I believe they must have the 'write personal information' permission for all users in order to update other users photos.

Is it possible to do this without making the user a domain admin and if so how?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Delegation of Control to grant the user the appropriate permissions to the AD objects they need to write to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are third-party tools that let users update their personal info, photos, etc without making them domain admins. Here's an example of such solution: http://www.adaxes.com/active-directory_self-service.htm

You can configure a self-service web UI and specify, what users can see and edit there by creating a Security role for this. Such approach doesn't require any additional tools that requires teaching users how to use it. They just go to a web page in a browser and do only what you let them.